# Is it true that for every $p$ and $q$ prime there exist infinitely many $k$ such that $p^k - 1$ is divisible by $q$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, p-adic-number-theory

This question is interesting because it helps to ask for another question:

What is multiplicative group of algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$?

I know that for algebraic extension $\mathbb{F}_q \supset \mathbb{F}_p$, it's true that $(\mathbb{F}_q)^* =$ ciclic group on $q - 1$ element.

If the answer for question in title is yes, then we know a lot of subgroups of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$. More presicely we know, that for every n there exists subgroup $\mathbb{Z} /n\mathbb{Z} \subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$ .

I know that $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ has the same property. If I'm right that  $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} = \times_r \mathbb{Z}_r$, where $r$ is prime, and  $\mathbb{Z}_r$ is $r$-adic group.

Is it true that $\bar{\mathbb{F}} _p^* =\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: Do you mean “is divisible by $q?$” As your title is written, only   finitely many $k$ have $p^k-1\mid q$ because $p^k-1>q$ if $k>q.$

Comment: There are no elements of order $p$ in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}^*$. So $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is a subgroup if and only if $\gcd(p,n)=1$.

Comment: Also $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$ has no torsion elements, but all the elements of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}^*$ are torsion.

Comment: I think your question is if $p^k-1$ is divisible by $q$ infinitely often, then the answer is yes, specifically just look at $p^k -1 \equiv 0 \mod q$ and we see this will happen at least as often as $k$ is a multiple of $q-1$ as guaranteed by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Merosity, Thank you for your answer,  I mean that: if you have fixed $p$ and $q$ does exist infinitely many $k$ such that $p^k - 1$ is divisible by q?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thank you for your answer, I have mistaken in my question. I wanted to ask: if you have fixed $p$ and $q$ does exist infinitely many $k$ such that $p^k - 1$ is divisible by q?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thanks for answer. You are right about $p$, if I'm right then it is the case when $q = p$ in my question. If I consider $q \ne p$ then I have not this problem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I'm not sure that I use right definition of $\widehat{Z}$. If we use definition $\widehat{Z} = \times_r \mathbb{Z}_r$. There are no torsion in $ \mathbb{Z}_r$, aren't there?

Comment: If $q\mid p^k-1$ then $q\mid p^{mk}-1$ for all $m$. Correct, in the additive group of $r$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_r$ (assuming that is what you meant) there is no torsion. But every element of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ belongs to some $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$, so they have (multiplicative) order that is a factor of $p^k-1$. That is, all the elements are of finite order.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!