# What is multiplicative group $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$ for algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

We know a lot of subgroups of  $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$:

$\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z} \subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$ if $q \ne p$ is prime. It easy to check using fact that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ and the fact that for every $q \ne p$ prime there exist $n$ such that $p^n - 1$ is divisible by $q$.

Is it true, that $\mathbb{Z}/(q\mathbb{Z})^m\subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$? What about $\mathbb{Z}/(q^m\mathbb{Z})\subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$? And  what other subgroups does it have?

Comment: Hmm. It might have been better to edit [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138374/11619) with these refinements. Particularly as there were no answers there. Now that question will become an orphan. And that's bad for site hygiene :-)

Comment: No major worries, yet. Things like this happen to new users. However, the site really wants to discourage this, so next time just edit the first version. Interested people will still find it! I will now close it as a duplicate of this for I think that is for the best. This version is better thought out, I think.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I'm going to follow your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ as

$$ \lim_{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}} $$

This can be thought of as the union of the $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$ by gluing them appropriately. The reason to introduce the $n!$ is to ensure that these can be glued.

Then, a finite subgroup $H \subset \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}^*$ is contained in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n!}}$ for some $n$. Since the unit group of each of these is cyclic, it is easy to sea that $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}^*$ if and only if $m | p^{n!} - 1$ for some $n$.

This happens if and only if $m$ is coprime to $p$ (remember that $m| p^{\phi(m)} - 1$ if they are coprime).

Observe that this actually characterises all of the finite subgroups.

If you want a more specific description, note that we can take $n$th roots of any $n$ coprime to $p$. Hence, this group is isomorphic to the localisation of the integers away from $p$. That is,

$$ \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} / \mathbb{Z}$$

(don't confuse the last bit of notation with $p$-adics)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the group is isomorphic to
$$
\prod_{q\neq p} \mu_{q^{\infty}}
$$
where product runs over all primes not equal to $q$ and $\mu_{q^{\infty}}$ is a $q$-prufer group
$$
\mu_{q^{\infty}} = \mathrm{colim}_{n}\mathbb{Z}/q^{n}\mathbb{Z}.
$$
In other words, it is a smallest abelian group which contains all finite cyclic groups order prime to $p$.

To show this, we'll use the following facts:

- The colimit of all finite cyclic groups is isomorphic to
  $$
  A:=\mathrm{colim}_{n} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \simeq \prod_{q}\mu_{q^\infty}
  $$
  by Chinese remainder theorem.
- The algebraic closure of finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is isomorphic to the colimit of all finite extensions
  $$
  \mathrm{colim}_{n} \mathbb{F}_{p^n}.
  $$
  Note that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ when $n|m$. By taking the unit group, we get
  $$
  \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p^{\times}  \simeq \mathrm{colim}_{n} \mathbb{F}_{p^n}^{\times} \simeq \mathrm{colim}_{n} \mathbb{Z}/(p^{n} - 1)\mathbb{Z}
  $$
  which is naturally a subgroup of the above group $A$.
- For any prime $q\neq p$ and $e\geq 1$, there exists $n$ such that $q^{e}$ divides $p^{n} - 1$. This is because of the Euler's theorem: we can simply set $n = \phi(q^{e}) = q^{e-1}(q-1)$.

Now, we are ready to prove our claim. First, for any prime $q\neq p$ and $e\geq 1$, there exists $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}/q^{e}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^{n}- 1)$. By using Chinese Remainder Theorem, this proves that any finite cyclic group whose order is prime to $p$ is a subgroup of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_{p}^{\times}$. So we have
$$
\prod_{q\neq p}\mu_{q^{\infty}} \subseteq \bar{\mathbb{F}}_{p}^{\times} \subset A = \prod_{q}\mu_{q^{\infty}}.
$$
The equality follows from the fact that our group can't contain element of order $p$.